# XSLT - "Apply" updates to another file

Tags: xslt

I have some Tomcat configuration that I'm trying to automate changing. Something might look like this:

```
<web-app>
  <!-- many other configuration options here... -->
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <!-- many other configuration options here... -->
<web-app>
```

And I want to update just the one value, leaving the other stuff untouched. So I defined a file with the same structure, only the value I want to change in it:

```
<web-app>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
<web-app>
```

Here is my XSLT, feeding it the update file as the input and the "default" TC configuration file path as a param:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <xsl:param name="tcInputFilePath" />
  <xsl:param name="tcInputFile" select="document($tcInputFilePath)" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$tcInputFile/*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically, I want a copy of the `$tcInputFile`, with changes applied from the update file. My guess is, I need some way to look up the same path in the update file as I'm traversing the TC file, then testing to see if that path has no child nodes, and apply the `value-of` instead of the `copy` if so. I just don't know how to select the "same node" in the other document while traversing. Help?

Answer (score 1):

See http://xslt-3-by-example.blogspot.com/2017/06/using-xslevaluate-and-path-function-to.html for a generic XSLT 3 solution to a similar problem although there the input has empty elements to be updated, for your case you would need to explain and implement a way to check the relevant element. And that solutions needs `xsl:evaluate` which is only available in the commercial versions of Saxon 9.8 and 9.9.

As Saxon 9.8 and 9.9 all editions support the `transform` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-transform this problem can be solved in these XSLT 3 processors also by generating a stylesheet on the fly and running it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-alias"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="config-doc">
    <web-app>
      <foo-config>
          <foo-value>foo</foo-value>
      </foo-config>
      <!-- many other configuration options here... -->
      <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
      </session-config>
      <!-- many other configuration options here... -->
      <bar-config>
          <bar-value>bar</bar-value>
      </bar-config>
    </web-app>      
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

  <xsl:variable name="stylesheet">
      <axsl:stylesheet version="3.0" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
          <axsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="//text()[normalize-space()]">
              <axsl:template match="{path()}">{.}</axsl:template>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </axsl:stylesheet>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select="transform(map { 'source-node' : $config-doc, 'stylesheet-node' : $stylesheet })?output"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There the main config document is inlined but you can of course use `document` or `doc` instead to load it.

Online example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtM.